# Is it possible to call one event without disrupting another with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to start a command with the `on_message` event, which would eventually prompt a message to react to. I then want to see who reacted to that, with the `on_reaction_add` (or `on_raw_reaction_add`) event. However, the client will only pay attention to one event at a time. Is it possible to, in a way, nest the `on_reaction_add`/`on_raw_reaction_add` into the `on_message` event?

I currently have:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("hi"):
        msg = await message.channel.send("Hello!")
        await msg.add_reaction("")
        while True:
            print("Looping...")
            time.sleep(1)
```

The while loop isn't permanent; just a way to show that the `on_message` event is still ongoing. Trying to nest in:

```
        await msg.add_reaction("")
        async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
            if payload.message_id == msg.id:
                if payload.emoji == ""
                    print(payload.member)
        while True:
            ...
```

doesn't work, nor does:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    ...

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    ...
```

I get this makes sense because two events can't run simultaneously, but is there a way to get this to work out?

For reference, [here is what happens currently](https://clipchamp.com/watch/7YkqVXdhMyQ), pardon my censoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what should work here is using `on_reaction_add()` outside the `on_message()` which is ran whenever a message is reacted to by anyone (user or bot).

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("hi"):
        msg = await message.channel.send("Hello!")
        await msg.add_reaction("")


@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction.emoji == "":
        print('Wave')
    print(reaction)
    print(user)
```

If you want to check if the reacted to message was sent by the bot then you could add a `if reaction.message.author == bot.user:` statement.

Comment: This works for the original reaction that the bot does, but any other reaction following it isn't processed while on_message is going.

Comment: events *can* happen asynchronously (they are async functions) check your code again, try to see if it prints anything *at all* on the second event

Comment: I did try again, but it still doesn't work: https://clipchamp.com/watch/7YkqVXdhMyQ (excuse my bad censoring, lol!) Once the while loop starts (or  any code that continuously runs), no reactions are picked up.

Comment: You shouldn't use `time.sleep()` with async functions. Try using `asyncio.sleep(1)`

Comment: Huh, using asyncio.sleep seemed to fix it. I tried it with a different type of loop not involving sleep at all and it didn't work. Thanks so much for the help everyone!! :)